# How to Clicked ok button of messagebox pops up on click the xyz application from my c# application

Tags: c#

i am trying to click the ok button of messagebox pops up when i click the button of xyz application from my c# application. i have tried the following code so that the button of xyz is clicked but C# application freeze after pops up message box is appeared.
i have created two button
button1- to click the button of xyz application
button2- to click the ok button of message box.

//button1 code

```
 IntPtr maindHwnd = FindWindow(null,"xyz application");
        if (maindHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
           
            IntPtr panel = FindWindowEx(maindHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "MDIClient", null);
            IntPtr panel1 = FindWindowEx(panel, IntPtr.Zero, "TAveForm", null);
            IntPtr panel2 = FindWindowEx(panel1, IntPtr.Zero, "TPanel", "Panel5");
            IntPtr panel3 = FindWindowEx(panel2, IntPtr.Zero, "TPanel", null);
            IntPtr childHwnd = FindWindowEx(panel3, IntPtr.Zero, "TBitBtn", "Save");


            if (childHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
               
                SendMessage(childHwnd, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
           }
```

//button2 code

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Error");
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr childHwnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Ok");   
            if (childHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SendMessage(childHwnd, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);     
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static public extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static public extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rectangle lpRect);

    var hwnd = FindWindow(null, "WindowTitle");
    if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
         if (GetWindowRect(hwnd, out Rectangle rect))
         {
             // rect..
         }
    }
```

You can use [pinvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net) for signature differences.